# Voximplant, RN: Change front camera to back camera

Tags: voximplant

I am integrating my React Native app with Voximplant platform via Voximplant RN SDK:
https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-voximplant

How do I change front camera to back? Can't find any information in documentations or any relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

To switch camera from front to back, you need to use [switchCamera](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/hardware/cameramanager#switchcamera) method like in the following example

```
import { Voximplant } from 'react-native-voximplant';

const switchCamera = () => {
    Voximplant.Hardware.CameraManager.getInstance().switchCamera(Voximplant.Hardware.CameraType.BACK);
}
```

You can also listen to [Voximplant.Hardware.CameraEvents.CameraSwitchDone](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/hardware/cameraeventtypes#cameraswitchdone) and [Voximplant.Hardware.CameraEvents.CameraSwitchError](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/hardware/cameraeventtypes#cameraswitcherror) events to monitor status of camera change